# Delay in start of play music in SimpleExoPlayer android

Tags: android, performance, audio, exoplayer, audio-player

I am building Music App in which I have uploaded music on firebase. I am using SimpleExoPlayer and PlayerView to run the music. The problem is when I click on the music, the music start after 10 seconds or more. I search it but did not find any solution

ExoPLayer library:

```
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.1"
```

public void initPlayer(MusicModel dataModel) {

```
    if (playerLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE && !isFullScreenOn) {

        playerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    assignPlayerLayout(dataModel);
    assignFullScreenPlayerLayout(dataModel);
    try {
        playerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(0);
        playerView.setCameraDistance(10);
        playerView.setShowFastForwardButton(false);
        playerView.setShowRewindButton(false);
        playerView.setShowNextButton(false);
        playerView.setShowPreviousButton(false);

        playerView.setShutterBackgroundColor(R.color.white);

        simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE)
                .build();

        simpleExoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true);
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(MainActivity.this,
                Util.getUserAgent(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(getString(dataModel.getAudioFile())));

        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);


        simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
        // Tell it to play the sound

        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        isPlaying = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("except",e.toString());
    }

}
```

Please give me a solution

> Blockquote

, I shall be very thankful to you.